# Jaccard vs. Cosine similarity for measuring distance between two words (fasttext)

Tags: nlp, distance, trigonometry, similarity, fasttext

These two distance measurements seem to be the most common in NLP from what I've read. I'm currently using cosine similarity (as does the gensim.fasttext distance measurement). Is there any case to be made for the use of Jaccard instead? Does it even work with only single words as input (with the use of ngrams I suppose)?

```py
ft = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')
distance = scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(ft['word1'], ft['word2'])
```

Comment: Jaccard is applied over sets of items, so not sure how it would be applied to 2 word-vectors (each with a fixed n number of dimensions). Can you be more specific what you're considering - for example, with code showing the calculation applied to some data?

Comment: Sure, I've added what I use until now. To use Jaccard I would need to work with the n-grams (length 5 for the model I use). I'm just not sure if it would even make sense or if cosine distance is best for this case anyway

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I could imagine Jaccard similarity over bags-of-ngrams being useful for something. You could try some experiments to see if it correlates with good performance on some particular word-to-word task.

Maybe: typo correction? Or perhaps, when using a plain, non-Fasttext set-of-word-vectors, you might try synthesizing vectors for OOV words, by some weighted average of the most ngram-Jaccard-similar existing words? (In both cases: other simple comparisons, like edit-distance or shared-substring counting, might do better.)

But, I've not noticed projects using Jaccard-over-ngrams in lieu of whole-word-vector to whole-word-vector comparisons, nor libraries offering it as part of their interfaces/examples.

You've also only described its potential use very vaguely, "with the use of ngrams I suppose", with no code either demonstrating such calculation, or the results of such calculation being put to any use.

So potential usefulness seems like a research conjecture that you'd need to probe with your own experiments.